# using highcharts in android

Tags: javascript, android, highcharts

I m trying to run my html and js code in android studio.but i failed.Can anyon1 tell me what shold i do :

I took an example of html and js from highchart site.I save my html and js file as demo.html in raw folder in res.

> **My java code is** :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activitytml);

    WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/demo.html");

}
```

when i run this code...only a blank screen occured..with no outpu
and i m using webview in xml file. Plzz can anyone help me. I got the blank screen in emulator.I m able to call the html page but when i make piechart using html and js. then it returns nothing. screen is blank.
can anyonehelp me out plzz.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is any JS working for you? Is the demo you are trying to load dependent on jQuery? (e.g. uses jQuery like `$('#container')` etc.) If yes - is jQuery loaded?

Comment: yes..i used jquery. but it is not running

Comment: i m using following script for example....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324431/using-highcharts-in-android

Comment: Have you tested (loaded in the same way) any other JS (e.g. simple script to test any changes in DOM or something you are using) to see it it is working? If you need jQuery then load it. If it is not working you should find out why - wrong file / wrong path / JS not loaded / etc.

Comment: i tested..with a short code..it worked..but when i paste this code in demo.html..then it is not giveing the proper output

Comment: What kind of errors are you having or what is not proper in the output? It doesn't look like a Highcharts problem. Please provide more precise info and full answers so I do not have to ask for everything - just to save out time.

Comment: wait....i update my code..

Comment: i run given's link code then i should get a pie chart as output but there is a blanck screen...no pie chart is there..i dont get the result of code..i dont knw what is happning..

Comment: i m using http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ this html and js code..as example

Comment: when i run this code in notepad..it runs properly..but when i run it in android studio it is no giving any output...